# Search Problem when "1" is present in query string

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

Suppose I have 3 products (**mix 1, mix 2, mix 3**) in my store. Now when I search for "**mix**" all three products showing. When I search for "**mix 2**", "**mix 2**" product is showing, when search for "**mix 3**", "**mix 3**" product is coming, But when I search for "**mix 1**" **all three product is showing**.

[image]

I have changed the following code in 
app/code/core/Mage/catalogsearch/model/Resource/Fulltext.php file

from

$likeCond = '(' . join(' **OR** ', $like) . ')';

to

$likeCond = '(' . join(' **AND** ', $like) . ')';

and only name attribute is searchable in quick search and in admin section "**like**" selected for "**Search Type**".

Now I don't understand why all three product showing when I search for "mix 1". Please help.